# How to dynamically allocate arrays inside a kernel?

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu

I need to dynamically allocate some arrays inside the kernel function. How can a I do that?

My code is something like that:

```
__global__ func(float *grid_d,int n, int nn){  
    int i,j;  
    float x[n],y[nn];  
    //Do some really cool and heavy computations here that takes hours.  
}
```

But that will not work. If this was inside the host code I could use malloc. cudaMalloc needs a pointer on host, and other on device. Inside the kernel function I don't have the host pointer.

So, what should I do?

If takes too long (some seconds) to allocate all the arrays (I need about 4 of size n and 5 of size nn), this won't be a problem. Since the kernel will probably run for 20 minutes, at least.

Comment: You probably want to read the section on [dynamic memory allocation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) in device code in the [CUDA C programmers guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations).  This capability requires compute capability 2.0 or greater in your GPU.

Comment: What is the configuration (blocks, threads) you will be running this kernel on? What are the typical ranges of `n` and `nn` (for small sizes you might squeeze them into registers, or shared memory).

Answer (score 31):

Dynamic memory allocation is only supported on compute capability 2.x and newer hardware. You can use either the C++ new keyword or malloc in the kernel, so your example could become:

```
__global__ func(float *grid_d,int n, int nn){  
    int i,j;  
    float *x = new float[n], *y = new float[nn];   
}
```

This allocates memory on a local memory runtime heap which has the lifetime of the context, so make sure you free the memory after the kernel finishes running if your intention is not to use the memory again. You should also note that runtime heap memory cannot be accessed directly from the host APIs, so you cannot pass a pointer allocated inside a kernel as an argument to `cudaMemcpy`, for example.

Comment: I have a similar situation where I need to have dynamically allocated arrays. Those arrays has to accessed by every thread for writing purpose. I am confused that if I declare this dynamic allocation process inside the kernel then, would it create 4 times such arrays if the dimensions of kernel are (1,4) i.e. nThreads = 4 and nBlocks = 1.

Comment: Is `free` appropriate here, or is there another function for freeing from the local heap inside a kernel?

Comment: @landau No you just use free or delete

Answer (score 16):

@talonmies answered your question on how to dynamically allocate memory within a kernel. This is intended as a supplemental answer, addressing performance of `__device__ malloc()` and an alternative you might want to consider.

Allocating memory dynamically in the kernel can be tempting because it allows GPU code to look more like CPU code. But it can seriously affect performance. I wrote a self contained test and have included it below. The test launches some 2.6 million threads. Each thread populates 16 integers of global memory with some values derived from the thread index, then sums up the values and returns the sum.

The test implements two approaches. The first approach uses `__device__ malloc()` and the second approach uses memory that is allocated before the kernel runs.

On my 2.0 device, the kernel runs in 1500ms when using `__device__ malloc()` and 27ms when using pre-allocated memory. In other words, the test takes **56x longer** to run when memory is allocated dynamically within the kernel. The time includes the outer loop `cudaMalloc()` / `cudaFree()`, which is not part of the kernel. If the same kernel is launched many times with the same number of threads, as is often the case, the cost of the `cudaMalloc()` / `cudaFree()` is amortized over all the kernel launches. That brings the difference even higher, to around 60x.

Speculating, I think that the performance hit is in part caused by implicit serialization. The GPU must probably serialize all simultaneous calls to `__device__ malloc()` in order to provide separate chunks of memory to each caller.

The version that does not use `__device__ malloc()` allocates all the GPU memory before running the kernel. A pointer to the memory is passed to the kernel. Each thread calculates an index into the previously allocated memory instead of using a `__device__ malloc()`.

The potential issue with allocating memory up front is that, if only some threads need to allocate memory, and it is not known which threads those are, it will be necessary to allocate memory for all the threads. If there is not enough memory for that, it might be more efficient to reduce the number of threads per kernel call then using `__device__ malloc()`. Other workarounds would probably end up reimplementing what  `__device__ malloc()` is doing in the background, and would see a similar performance hit.

Test the performance of `__device__ malloc()`:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

const int N_ITEMS(16);

#define USE_DYNAMIC_MALLOC

__global__ void test_malloc(int* totals)
{
  int tx(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);

  int* s(new int[N_ITEMS]);

  for (int i(0); i < N_ITEMS; ++i) {
    s[i] = tx * i;
  }

  int total(0);
  for (int i(0); i < N_ITEMS; ++i) {
    total += s[i];
  }

  totals[tx] = total;

  delete[] s;
}

__global__ void test_malloc_2(int* items, int* totals)
{
  int tx(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);

  int* s(items + tx * N_ITEMS);

  for (int i(0); i < N_ITEMS; ++i) {
    s[i] = tx * i;
  }

  int total(0);
  for (int i(0); i < N_ITEMS; ++i) {
    total += s[i];
  }

  totals[tx] = total;
}

int main()
{
  cudaError_t cuda_status;

  cudaSetDevice(0);

  int blocks_per_launch(1024 * 10);
  int threads_per_block(256);

  int threads_per_launch(blocks_per_launch * threads_per_block);

  int* totals_d;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&totals_d, threads_per_launch * sizeof(int));

  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  cudaEventCreate(&start);
  cudaEventCreate(&stop);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

#ifdef USE_DYNAMIC_MALLOC
  cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, threads_per_launch * N_ITEMS * sizeof(int));

  test_malloc<<<blocks_per_launch, threads_per_block>>>(totals_d);
#else
  int* items_d;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&items_d, threads_per_launch * sizeof(int) * N_ITEMS);

  test_malloc_2<<<blocks_per_launch, threads_per_block>>>(items_d, totals_d);

  cudaFree(items_d);
#endif

  cuda_status = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  if (cuda_status != cudaSuccess) {
    printf("Error: %d\n", cuda_status);
    exit(1);
  }

  cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  float elapsedTime;
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop);

  printf("Elapsed: %f\n", elapsedTime);

  int* totals_h(new int[threads_per_launch]);
  cuda_status = cudaMemcpy(totals_h, totals_d, threads_per_launch * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  if (cuda_status != cudaSuccess) {
    printf("Error: %d\n", cuda_status);
    exit(1);
  }

  for (int i(0); i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("%d ", totals_h[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  cudaFree(totals_d);
  delete[] totals_h;

  return cuda_status;
}
```

Output:

```
(test_malloc_2)
C:\rd\projects\test_cuda_malloc\Release>test_cuda_malloc.exe
Elapsed: 27.311169
0 120 240 360 480 600 720 840 960 1080

(test_malloc)
C:\rd\projects\test_cuda_malloc\Release>test_cuda_malloc.exe
Elapsed: 1516.711914
0 120 240 360 480 600 720 840 960 1080
```

Comment: You should time the cudaMalloc in the second test. Otherwise you are comparing a car ready to run (second test) to a stopped car in a garage (first test). Both kernels need the same storage requirements.

Comment: In addition to pQB objection: your `cudaMalloc` allocates one large array, and this is compared to allocation of 2.5million small matrices (for each thread one). Such a procedure is of course slower, and a test on CPU shows, that your reported 60x slowdown is actually a good job (I get 1000x times slowdown, provided code does not segfault -- allocator needs to handle so many matrices). Fair test is: allocate same (one) array, (1) per `cudaMalloc`, (2) per `kernel<<<1,1>>>`. I see the `kernel` allocation being slower ~3 times. So this is the true performance hit.

Comment: @pQB: Thanks. I had left the cudaMalloc() out of the timing, assuming that it would not be measurable. To my surprise, adding it in did cause a change, going from 60x to 56x. I've updated the answer and added a blurb about implications of including the cudaMalloc() / cudaFree() in the timing.

Comment: @PMarecki: The purpose of the test was to show the performance implications of using `__device__ malloc()` and to show an alternative way of accomplishing the task for which many would consider `__device__ malloc()`. The purpose was not to compare the performance of a single `cudaMalloc()` with a single `__device__ malloc()`.

Comment: @RogerDahl neat test!  I think the main point is to show the difference in allocating many small matrices, either on the device or on the host. But, regardless, with the same number of malloc calls.  I'd think that "of course" a single malloc call is going to be faster than many individual malloc calls.

Answer (score 2):

If the value of n and nn were known before the kernel is called, then why not cudaMalloc the memory on host side and pass in the device memory pointer to the kernel?

Comment: Because each kernel must own one array.

Comment: Are you launching multiple kenel concurrently? Couldn't you allocate sufficient space and each kernel just shares part of it?

Comment: if i lauch, for example, 1000 kernels and if i need 10 arrays of size n. The i should make 10 arrays of size n*1000? And share this across the kernels using threadid and blockid?

Answer (score 2):

Ran an experiment based on the concepts in @rogerdahl's post.  Assumptions:

- 4MB of memory allocated in 64B chunks.
- 1 GPU block and 32 warp threads in that block
- Run on a P100

The malloc+free calls local to the GPU seemed to be much faster than the `cudaMalloc` + `cudaFree` calls.  The program's output:

```
Starting timer for cuda malloc timer
Stopping timer for cuda malloc timer
         timer for cuda malloc timer took 1.169631s
Starting timer for device malloc timer
Stopping timer for device malloc timer
         timer for device malloc timer took 0.029794s
```

I'm leaving out the code for `timer.h` and `timer.cpp`, but here's the code for the test itself:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/system/cuda/error.h>

#include "timer.h"

static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *, unsigned, const char *, cudaError_t);
#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) CheckCudaErrorAux(__FILE__,__LINE__, #value, value)

const int BLOCK_COUNT = 1;
const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 32;
const int ITERATIONS = 1 << 12;
const int ITERATIONS_PER_BLOCKTHREAD = ITERATIONS / (BLOCK_COUNT * THREADS_PER_BLOCK);

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 64;


void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *file, unsigned line, const char *statement, cudaError_t err) {
    if (err == cudaSuccess)
        return;
    std::cerr << statement<<" returned " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << "("<<err<< ") at "<<file<<":"<<line << std::endl;
    exit (1);
}

__global__ void mallocai() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS_PER_BLOCKTHREAD; ++i) {
        int * foo;
        foo = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRAY_SIZE);
        free(foo);
    }
}

int main() {

    Timer cuda_malloc_timer("cuda malloc timer");

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++ i) {
        if (i == 1) cuda_malloc_timer.start(); // let it warm up one cycle
        int * foo;
        cudaMalloc(&foo, sizeof(int) * ARRAY_SIZE);
        cudaFree(foo);
    }
    cuda_malloc_timer.stop_and_report();
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    Timer device_malloc_timer("device malloc timer");
    device_malloc_timer.start();
    mallocai<<<BLOCK_COUNT, THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>();
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    device_malloc_timer.stop_and_report();
}
```

If you find mistakes, please lmk in the comments, and I'll try to fix them.

And I ran them again with larger everything:

```
const int BLOCK_COUNT = 56;
const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 1024;
const int ITERATIONS = 1 << 18;
const int ITERATIONS_PER_BLOCKTHREAD = ITERATIONS / (BLOCK_COUNT * THREADS_PER_BLOCK);

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1024;
```

And cudaMalloc was still slower by a lot:

```
Starting timer for cuda malloc timer
Stopping timer for cuda malloc timer
         timer for cuda malloc timer took 74.878016s
Starting timer for device malloc timer
Stopping timer for device malloc timer
         timer for device malloc timer took 0.167331s
```

Comment: Also of note, `malloc` + `free` took basically the same amount of time as `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should test

```
cudaMalloc(&foo,sizeof(int) * ARRAY_SIZE * ITERATIONS);
cudaFree(foo);
```

instead

```
for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++ i) {
    if (i == 1) cuda_malloc_timer.start(); // let it warm up one cycle
    int * foo;
    cudaMalloc(&foo, sizeof(int) * ARRAY_SIZE);
    cudaFree(foo);
}
```